# Meaning of these two quotes

Tags: sentence-meaning, quotations

Following are the two quotes which I received from Hike daily services.

> "Speak softly and carry a big stick; you will go far."  - Theodore
>   Roosevelt
>
> "Each time I free a child, I feel it is something closer to God." 
>   - Kailash Satyarthi

What do they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't speak in a bellicose manner, but do have the capacity to use violence  to achieve your ends, and you will succeed.

The implication is that there is no need to remind others with your words that you can harm them if you actually have the power to do so. They will be reluctant to rile you or to do you harm when they see that you are brandishing a weapon.  Applied to a nation, it would be advice to maintain a strong military.

The second could mean something like "Whenever I free a child (from the bondage of child labor) I feel as though I've drawn closer to God."  The referent of "it" is not perfectly clear.  It could refer to the act of freeing a child, and be saying that the act is a good and charitable act,  founded in love, and that it is therefore closer to the way God would have us act towards each other than other kinds of acts.

Answer (score 2):

Theodore Roosevelt was a President of the United States, and he believed that the most effective diplomacy was to be very polite and reserved, but also to have the most effective military to back you up.

I am not familiar with Kailash Satyarthi, but he seems to be a priest and child labor activist who won the Nobel Peace Prize last year.

These seem to be mostly about context, and also are likely explained if you just put the quote into Google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just for your information, Kailash Satyarthi won a nobel peace prize along with much popular Malala Yousafzai in the same year 2014. TRomano explains the second one correctly.

Answer (score 1):

These two [English Quotes](https://www.examweb.in/english-quotes-for-ugc-net-english-lecturer-pgt-exam-1209) have deep meanings. The first one means that if a person is to get good success in life, he must adopt duel approach towards it. He should be both soft spoken and strict in action according to the situation.This is also a good quality of a great diplomat like **Theodore Roosevelt.** 
The second one suggests that **Kailash Satyarthi** feels himself closer to God when he does a good work like freeing a child from the bondage of Child Labour.

Kailash Satyarthi is a Social Activist who is working against Child Labour. He has been fighting against this evil through a movement called Bachpan Bachao Andolan ( Save Childhood Movement) since 1980.